# Windows Azure maxReceivedMessageSize set

Tags: wcf, azure

I have a problem with large amount of data that I want to send to my WCF WebRole.
I get (413) too large data error. I quite new in Azure and WCF. I created a new service for sending images to WCF (LargeObject.svc) and tried to configure binding and endpoint for it.

This is the ServerSideCode:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IImage" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
               maxArrayLength="200000000"
               maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRouteService"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBinding_IRouteService">
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/routeservice/routeservice.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRouteService"
    contract="Route.IRouteService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IRouteService" />
  <endpoint address="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/routeservice/routeservice.svc/binaryHttp"
    binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IRouteService"
    contract="Route.IRouteService" name="CustomBinding_IRouteService" />
  <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:81/Implementation/LargeObject.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IImage"
            contract="ILargeObject" name="BasicHttpBinding_IImageSvc"/>
</client>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1048576" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

I have also a client Application in Windows Phone, code:

```
string endPointAddress = (Application.Current as TravelerMobile.App).ServerUriString("LargeObject.svc");

        LargeObjectClient client = new LargeObjectClient(new BasicHttpBinding(),
            new EndpointAddress(endPointAddress));


        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(image);
        wb.SaveJpeg(stream, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
        byte[] byteImage = stream.ToArray();

        client.AddImageAsync(new LargeObject.AddImageRequest
        {
            Image = byteImage,
            Latitude = latitude,
            Longitude = longitude,
            UserId = Helpers.GetUserId()
        });
```

I also tried to configure BasicHttpBinding on client side by set maxRevieved and maxBuffered properties, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

p.s That's a Windows Azure WCF project, so I have a default endpoint - but I don't know how to set to it maxReceivedMessageSize .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following link on stackoverflow who had the same problem, hope it works for you too, [Azure WCF Webrole error: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755529/azure-wcf-webrole-error-the-remote-server-returned-an-unexpected-response-413)

as you made the maximum bytes to be transferred in the MaxReceivedMessageSize, I think you should do this to in the ReaderQuotas tag.

another thing, you have to put in consideration, I don't know what type of storage you are using but there are some storage that doesn't allow you to upload more than 4MB for the file.  for example for each blockblob the maximum size for a block is 4 MB and also for the pageblob the maximum size is 4 MB.

you can also check this link on msdn, they had the same problem: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/39bfad06-97c0-4a98-b9fb-87879bab9414

Comment: Thank you very much. I didin't noticed that I always set the "name" attribute. Now, without it, my binding is "degault one". Thanks again.